# CodeIgniter: Limit cookies only on maindomain.tld and www.maindomain.tld

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I'm working on some project on CodeIgniter and I would like to limit cookies on maindomain.tld and www.maindomain.tld, because I have another, third, domain another.maindomain.tld which has installed same application but with a little different features. My config for maindomain.tld is like that:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "maindomain.tld";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

And for another.maindomain.tld:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "another.maindomain.tld";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

Cookies from maindomain.tld are working on another.maindomain.tld which shouldn't be, because databases are different and there might not be same user with same id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to simply use prefix.

http://codeigniter.fr/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html

> The prefix is only needed if you need to avoid name collisions with
>   other identically named cookies for your server.

So try this:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "main";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "maindomain.tld";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;


$config['cookie_prefix']    = "sub";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "another.maindomain.tld";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

Comment: Thank you, that's solution :) (will accept when it'll be possible)